# Using standard normal to find the expectation of Rayleigh distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let  have the Rayleigh density given by 
$$f(r)= re^{-0.5r^2}$$ 
where $r\geq0$. Let $Z$ have the standard normal density. Use the mean and variance of $Z$ to find $E[R]$ without any further integration.

I'm having trouble finding the connection between $R$ and $Z$.

Comment: The rayleigh distribution is similary to the normal but defined only for nonnegative $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the folded normal distribution. Let $Y$ be the **folded** distributed variable and $Z$ the standard normal distribution. Then $Y=|Z|$.  $Y$ has a mean of $\mu_y=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ and a variance of $\sigma_y^2=1-\mu_y^2=1-\frac{2}{\pi}$

Now we use the  definition of $E(Y^2)$ in terms of the expected value and variance to calculate it. $$\mathbb E(Y^2)=\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}}\cdot \int_0^{\infty} y^2\cdot e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} \, dy=\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}}\cdot \int_0^{\infty} y\cdot \underbrace{y\cdot e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}}_{f_R(y)} \, dy=\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}}\cdot  \mathbb E(R)$$

$$\mathbb E(Y^2)=Var(Y)+\mathbb [E(Y)]^2=1-\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi}=1$$

Finally use the results of the two last lines and deduce $\mathbb E(R)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $var(Z) = 1$,$E(Z) = 0$, and $var(Z) = E(Z^2) - E(Z)^2$, we know $E(Z^2) = 1$. That is,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  z^2 e^{-z^2/2} \; dz = 1$$

Hence
$$ \int_0^{\infty}  z^2 e^{-z^2/2} \; dz = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
Replacing $z$ with $r$ in the integral above, we have 
$$E(R) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$